# Rails spree commerce,spree install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I keep getting this when I run spree install

```
Polyglot: found more than one candidate for C:/Sites/mystore8/config/environment.rb: C:/Sites/mystore8/config/environment.rb,C:/Sites/mystore8/config/environment.rb
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This was filed on Spree and fixed there too: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/3331.